# Oracle SQL - order table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle SQL and have a table below.

```
TABLE NAME : ORDERS
CNUM     AMT    SNUM
1001     1000   2001
1002     2000   2002
1001     1500   2001
1001     500    2001
```

need to get only those data where cnum (customer number) is serviced by more than 3 snum(sales person) from this above table

thank you
Asit

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
select cnum, count(*), sum(amount)  
  from orders
 group by cnum
having count(*) > 3
```

Not sure what you need - aggregate result or every single row. If you need every row then try this one:

```
select * from (
select a.*, count(*) over(partition by cnum) cnt  
  from orders a
) 
where  cnt > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the analytic function **ROW_NUMBER**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY cnum ORDER BY snum) rn FROM t
  3  )
  4  SELECT cnum, amt, snum FROM DATA
  5  WHERE rn >=3;

      CNUM        AMT       SNUM
---------- ---------- ----------
      1001       1500       2001

SQL>
```

Based on your sample data, the above gives the result including 3 snum for cnum, if you want more than 3, then replace `>=` with `>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tab
     AS (SELECT 1001 CNUM, 1000 AMT, 2001 SNUM FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1002, 2000, 2002 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1001, 1500, 2001 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1001, 500, 2001 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT cnum
    FROM tab
GROUP BY cnum
  HAVING COUNT (*) >= 3;
```

If you only need the cnum and the snum you could do the following witch is partially taken from Rusty's answer:

```
WITH tab
     AS (SELECT 1001 CNUM, 1000 AMT, 2001 SNUM FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1002, 2000, 2002 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1001, 1500, 2001 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1001, 500, 2001 FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT cnum, snum
  FROM (SELECT cnum, snum, COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY cnum) RANK FROM tab)
 WHERE RANK >= 3;
```

Comment: I have added what I think you need. The basic idea is taken from Rusty's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can group and count distinct `SNUM`s:

```
select CNUM 
from ORDERS
group by CNUM
having count(distinct SNUM) > 3
```